# SELECT several columns based on one condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, case, conditional-statements

Is there a way to generate more then one column based on one condition? My perception is like:

```
SELECT

CASE WHEN condition_column = 'condition true' and (condition_column2 = 'condition true' or condition_column3 = 'condition true')

THEN column1 as new_column1
AND column2 as new_column2
AND column3 as new_column3

ELSE column2 as new_column1
AND column3 as new_column2
AND column1 as new_column3
```

My current way to do this is like:

```
SELECT

CASE WHEN condition_column = 'condition true' and (condition_column2 = 'condition true' or condition_column3 = 'condition true')
THEN column1 ELSE column2 END AS new_column1,

CASE WHEN condition_column = 'condition true' and (condition_column2 = 'condition true' or condition_column3 = 'condition true')
THEN column2 ELSE column3 END AS new_column2,

CASE WHEN condition_column = 'condition true' and (condition_column2 = 'condition true' or condition_column3 = 'condition true')
THEN column3 ELSE column1 END AS new_column3
```

But that becomes a very long list of statements in case of complicated conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try a completely different approach. ***One of these***:

### CTE / `LEFT JOIN` / `UNION ALL`

1. Select all columns for the first case in a [**CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html).
2. Exclude already selected rows from second case.
3. `UNION ALL` with CTE.

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT tbl_id, col1, col2, col3
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  condition_col = 'cond true'
   AND    'cond true' IN (condition_col2, condition_col3)
   )
SELECT t.tbl_id, t.col2 AS new1, t.col3 AS new2, t.col1 AS new3
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN cte c USING (tbl_id)
WHERE  c.tbl_id IS NULL

UNION ALL
TABLE cte
ORDER BY tbl_id
```

`tbl_id` is the primary key in this scenario.

### Array

Arrays can only hold values of the same base type. If all involved columns share the **same type**, you pick a whole array based on a single condition. To unnest the array again, use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT tbl_id, a[1] AS new1, a[2] AS new2
FROM (
   SELECT tbl_id, CASE WHEN TRUE THEN ARRAY[col1, col2]
                                 ELSE ARRAY[col2, col3] END AS a
   FROM   tbl
   ) x;
```

If you have columns of different type, you could **cast** all to the same type, typically `text` (and optionally cast back) on the next level:

```
SELECT tbl_id, a[1] AS new1, a[2] AS new2
FROM (
   SELECT tbl_id, CASE WHEN TRUE THEN ARRAY[col1::text, col2::text]
                                 ELSE ARRAY[col2::text, col3::text] END AS a
   FROM   tbl
   ) x;
```

### Record

To avoid the subquery level and casting types, you could use a record type instead. The obstacle here is that Postgres can only unnest registered (well-known) record types.

```
SELECT tbl_id, (CASE WHEN TRUE THEN (col1::text, col2::int)
                               ELSE (col2::text, col3::int) END).*
FROM   tbl;
```

For an anonymous record, you'd get:

> ```
> ERROR:  record type has not been registered
> ```

But you can work with a **registered record type** - like the implicitly created type of a table or view or explicitly created with [`CREATE TYPE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtype.html). For the sake of this demo I create a type explicitly:

```
CREATE TYPE foo AS (new1 text, new2 int);
```

Then you can select multiple columns based on a single `CASE` expression and unnest the record in the same step:

```
SELECT tbl_id, (CASE WHEN TRUE THEN (col1::text, col2::int)::foo
                               ELSE (col2::text, col3::int)::foo END).*
FROM   tbl;
```

Works for columns of **any type** (even the same type). Enclosing parentheses are mandatory.

For ad-hoc queries you don't have to persist a new type. Create a temporary table instead, that dies with the session:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo (new1 text, new2 int);
SELECT ...
```